# Is there a way to save visual studio errors and exceptions to sql Database?

Tags: c#, sql

I wonder is there a way to save errors and exceptions to sql database to see all my mistake later? Copy and paste are easy way. I searched codes to save errors but found nothing. Please help.

Comment: there are dozens of solutions to this, many libraries already available online. And it's not even hard, at a trivial level, to catch an exception, write the details to the Windows Event log, or to a database, or a text file, (or whatever you like) using built-in .NET classes, and then continue. Plenty of examples of that online too. Seems like you didn't search very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/) (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) library. Log the errors in try catch. ELMAH exposes errors as URL to view logs like http://domainname/elmah.axd.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful library called [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog). Read through the documentation, it's very easy to set up and use. And [this Wiki](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) will walk you through setting up a database target.